# Daylight savings information for converting UTC dates

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, reporting

I am developing reports using Microsoft SQL Report Builder 2.0. One of my requirement is to display the timezone information by passing "Timezone Offset" (-08:00) as a parameter to the report. Based on the offset value, we convert a UTC date to its appropriate timezone value (using VB.NET) and display the same. However, this does not consider the daylight savings. Is there anyway to incorporate daylight savings related changes to our conversion?

FYI, the platform is .NET Framework 3.

Thanks,
Veera

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following:

- [TimeZone.GetDaylightChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.getdaylightchanges.aspx)
- [DaylightTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.daylighttime.aspx)
- [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx)

There are all sorts of properties and methods that you may be able to take advantage of.

Comment: Yes, all these (TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone) works on the local time zone of the system, But I want to get I want to display in different timezone I 'll be provided by the offset value.
Is there any way.
Thanks,
Veera

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer, If I want to acce.ss the timezone in the code. I need to add the "system.core" & then if imezonecreate a timezoninfo object and I can create custom timezone. Also we can get all timezones available zones from the system.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo_members(v=VS.100).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb309898(v=VS.100).aspx